# NodeJS HTTPS.get how to know the download is finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

I have got the following problem: I am downloading a file, and i want to do something as soon as it finishes. I actually want to require a .js file as soon as i got it downloaded

```
            var request = https.get('https://mypage/en.js').on('response', function (response) {
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                var info = (chunk);
                descriptionFile.write(info);
            });
            response.on('end', function(){ //do some stuff here


                response.end(); //doesnt work..
            })
        });

    require('./descriptionEN.js')
```

There seems to be no res.end().. How can i do this otherwise? How do i know my download is finished?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't define `res` anywhere.

Comment: @Quentin yea i fixed that. still doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: I"m not massively familiar with the API you are using, but the logic "When the response end event fires, trigger the response end" doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: When you receive the `end` event, the download is finished. See [this](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) as well.

Comment: Thank you all! I could fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve this problem. there is an end event on the stream.

```
const readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
});
readable.on('end', () => {
  console.log('There will be no more data.');
});
```